# How to get values of WPF ComboBox by index

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using WPF ComboBox,

I want to retrieve all the values from a `ComboBox` or a `ComboBoxItem` by using Index

```
var v = cmbSubject.Items.GetItemAt(0);
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Haven't you answered your question?

Comment: I agree with javi (+1). You sorta answered your own question. :) In case you haven't answered your own question could you provide us with more information?

Comment: way below SO standards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer

```
 var v = cmbSubject.Items.GetItemAt(0);
            DataRowView dv = (DataRowView)v;
            string strCmbItem = dv[1].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that ?

```
List<var> Items = cmbSubject.Items;
```

Answer (score 0):

Example XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="myComboBox" SelectedIndex="0" >
   <ComboBoxItem Content="Item one"></ComboBoxItem>
   <ComboBoxItem Content="Item two"></ComboBoxItem>
   <ComboBoxItem Content="Item three"></ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

The `ComboBox` in this example has 3 items, these are `ComboBoxItem`s. If you try to get the `Content` of a `ComboBox` you will need something like this:

```
String ContentOfItemOne = (myComboBox.Items[0] as ComboBoxItem).Content.ToString();
```

I hope it helps.